# Cant access PerfRawData or PerfFormattedData

Tags: wmi

The Win32_PerfFormattedData_* and Win32_PerfRawData_* classes are missing from my system.

I'm running Windows 7, 64-bit, and using [WMICodeCreator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) to browse the available classes. Neither WMICodeCreator nor my C# code can get information from them, and I have not been able to find any discussion boards talking about this particular issue.

All other WMI classes are working perfectly fine.

Could it be a service that I haven't started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the perfmon to see if counters are present. If you cannot see counters or perfmon displays some incoherent data, your counters are corrupted; you will have to rebuild counters.
Some links that can possibly help you:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2009/10/06/how-to-rebuild-performance-counters-on-windows-vista-server2008-7-server2008r2.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/perfctr/thread/51528a4d-509e-4f09-984d-367ecb4fff25