# Powershell 3.0 - Get-Counter -Continuous is returning Error c0000bc4

Tags: powershell

In trying to use "Get-Counter -Continuous", I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Counter -Continuous
Get-Counter : The default values for this command failed. Error: c0000bc4.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Counter -Continuous
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterPathTranslationFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand

Get-Counter : The specified object was not found on the computer.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Counter -Continuous
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand

Get-Counter : The default values for this command failed. Error: c0000bc4.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Counter -Continuous
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterPathTranslationFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand

Get-Counter : The specified object was not found on the computer.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Counter -Continuous
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand

Get-Counter : The default values for this command failed. Error: c0000bc4.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Counter -Continuous
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterPathTranslationFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand

Get-Counter : The specified object was not found on the computer.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Counter -Continuous
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand

Get-Counter : The default values for this command failed. Error: c0000bc4.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Counter -Continuous
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterPathTranslationFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand

Get-Counter : The specified object was not found on the computer.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Counter -Continuous
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand

Get-Counter : The default values for this command failed. Error: c0000bc4.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Counter -Continuous
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterPathTranslationFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand

Get-Counter : The specified object was not found on the computer.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Counter -Continuous
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand

Get-Counter : The default values for this command failed. Error: c0000bc4.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Counter -Continuous
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterPathTranslationFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand

Get-Counter : The specified object was not found on the computer.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Counter -Continuous
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand
```

I'm using Powershell 3.0 - I've tried this in Powershell ISE, the Powershell prompt and cmd prompt to no avail - all in admin mode.  If I run Get-Process, for example, I get back what I expected to see.

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: It runs fine on my machine. I wonder if you have a corrupted WMI or something that's giving bad data to the cmdlet.

Comment: Looks like your counter paths are messed up. What happens when you run                        `(get-counter -listset *).paths` ?

Comment: I can get different counter paths, but they don't match the `get-help` documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error codes for performance counters can be found at this URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373046(v=vs.85).aspx

The specific error code you mentioned, maps to this error:

```
0xC0000BC4 (PDH_INVALID_PATH)   The specified counter path could not be interpreted.
```

Please run this command to get a comprehensive list of counters on your system, and then select one to test out:

```
$AllCounters = Get-Counter -ListSet * | ForEach-Object -Process { $PSItem.Paths; $PSItem.PathsWithInstances; }

Get-Counter -Counter $AllCounters[5];
```

### EDIT: Adding Default Counter paths from my system

```
PS C:\Users\Trevor> (Get-Counter).CounterSamples.Path
\\cid-win81\network interface(intel[r] 82579lm gigabit network connection)\bytes total/sec
\\cid-win81\network interface(intel[r] centrino[r] ultimate-n 6300 agn)\bytes total/sec
\\cid-win81\network interface(isatap.{7cf0580e-071d-46ce-99fe-58328b0b7b35})\bytes total/sec
\\cid-win81\network interface(teredo tunneling pseudo-interface)\bytes total/sec
\\cid-win81\network interface(isatap.{11c74532-d485-4064-bcc4-3c595d90aec1})\bytes total/sec
\\cid-win81\network interface(isatap.{4c5f7956-2451-493b-8a9f-d0331c8d38d2})\bytes total/sec
\\cid-win81\processor(_total)\% processor time
\\cid-win81\memory\% committed bytes in use
\\cid-win81\memory\cache faults/sec
\\cid-win81\physicaldisk(_total)\% disk time
\\cid-win81\physicaldisk(_total)\current disk queue length
```

Comment: Okay, so I did this and got the `-ListSet` printing out.  Is there one that's better than others to test out?  I'm a totally noobie at this - thanks for your patience.

Comment: Well, I did get it - Instead of the path being `\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time`, I had to use `\Processor Information(_Total)\% Processor Time`.  Any idea why these would be different from examples in the `get-help`?  And still, I can't just do a `Get-Counter` to get a simple run-down...

Comment: Not really. You can pipe the output into clip.exe, and paste it into Notepad so you can look it over. :) Just do this: `$AllCounters | clip;`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know why the default paths would be wrong. I will update my answer with the default paths that I am seeing, when I run `Get-Counter` with no parameters on PowerShell v4 / Windows 8.1.

Comment: Is there a simple way to edit my default counter paths?

Comment: I don't know where that command gets the default counter paths. However, you can skip the "counter" cmdlets, and go directly to WMI to retrieve performance information. Here is a command that will list out all of the "perf" WMI classes: `Get-WmiObject -List *perf* | Sort-Object -Property Name;`

Comment: Okay, so for anyone else that stumbles on this thread - when I tried to access the WMI for the "perf" classes, none of them were available.  I searched and came across [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566743/cant-access-perfrawdata-or-perfformatteddata).  When I opened "perfmon", It had an error "Unable to add these counters", then listed out 7 counters.  I'm going to try to rebuild my counters as suggested in the link.